# CE Image tags in stash:set stop parsing when I add a stash:get

Tags: stash, ce-image

I had the following code which worked:

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="project:{segment_3}" scope="site"}

{exp:stash:set name="main_content"}

<div class="rel">
  <ul class="rslides">
    {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="project:{segment_3}:slider" scope="site"}
      {if project_slide_type == "Image"}
        <li>
          <a href="{exp:ce_img:single src='{project_slide_image}' output='{made}' quality='70' width='1800'}"></a>
        </li>
      {if:else}
        <li class="video_slide video-player">
          <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/{project_slide_video}?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="700" height="400" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </li>
      {/if}
    {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
  </ul>
</div>

{/exp:stash:set}

{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

But then I wanted to use a different stash list for logged in users. I couldn't apply `parse_conditionals="yes"` to the `stash:set` tag as there were other conditionals in there I don't won't parsed early. So I tried this:

```
{exp:stash:set name="logged_in" parse_conditionals="yes"}
      {if logged_out}
        {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="project:{segment_3}:slider" scope="site"}
      {/if}
      {if logged_in}
        {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="project:{segment_3}:slider:private" scope="site"}
      {/if}
    {/exp:stash:set}

    {exp:stash:get_list name="project:{segment_3}" scope="site"}

      {exp:stash:set name="main_content"}

        <div class="rel">
          <ul class="rslides">
            {exp:stash:get name="logged_in"}
              {if project_slide_type == "Image"}
                <li>
                  <a href="{exp:ce_img:single src='{project_slide_image}' output='{made}' quality='70' width='1800'}"></a>
                </li>
              {if:else}
                <li class="video_slide video-player">
                  <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/{project_slide_video}?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="700" height="400" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </li>
              {/if}
            {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
          </ul>
        </div>

      {/exp:stash:set}

    {/exp:stash:get_list}
```

But now, although the logged in / logged out functionality works, the CE Image tags don't parse. Looking at the template debugger output, it seems that the `{project_slide_image}` tags never parse. The only difference is the `stash:get` tag. I tried adding `parse_tags="yes"` on the `stash:set` tag as well as increasing the parse_depth, but nothing seems to make the tags parse.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! (Using EE 2.7.2, PHP 5.5.3 and Stash 2.5.3)